# Starting an .exe with two arguments from cmd in C# but arguments are not passed

Tags: c#, process.start

I have the following piece of code:

```cs
       public static void startApplicationWithParameters()
        {
            string pathToProgram = "path to exe";
            string pathToLogFile= "path to log file";
            string pathToConfigFile = "path to xml file";
            string arguments = pathToLogFile + " " + pathToConfigFile;
            Console.WriteLine(arguments);

            Process startProcess = new Process();
            startProcess.StartInfo.FileName = pathToProgram;
            startProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            startProcess.Start();
           
        }
```

Printing the arguments shows the paths separated with space as expected. However, when running the method I get this message in the console:

"Expected two command line arguments, one indicating a path for a log file and the second to an XML configuration file
Something went wrong when parsing command line options, stopping"

I'm trying to re-write a .bat file to c# that contains the following piece of code:

```
start /d %programPath% cmd.exe /k program.exe %programLogPath%\programLog.log %programConfigPath%\program.xml
```

The .bat file works as expected. What could be causing my error in the c# code? I read multiple threads about starting .exe file with c# but I couldn't find a solution.

I want the program to run in a separate console window and I don't want to wait for it to stop.

Comment: My guess is that the paths have spaces in, and that your code received *more* than two parameters. Try putting the paths in quotes: `string arguments = $"\"{pathToLogFile}\" \"{pathToConfigFile}\"";` - or better, use `ArgumentList` instead of `Arguments` (Not adding as an answer, as it's only a guess...)

Comment: It was the space in the paths, thank you very much, that resolved my problem!

Comment: Righto, will turn that into an answer.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to re-read the [mre] guidance before posting next questions... When @JonSkeet *had to guess* what is asked it really bad sign :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the paths have spaces in, and that your code received *more* than two parameters, instead of them not receiving the parameters at all.
Try putting the paths in quotes:

```cs
string arguments = $"\"{pathToLogFile}\" \"{pathToConfigFile}\"";
```

Or better, use [`ArgumentList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.argumentlist) instead of `Arguments`, as then you don't need any quoting or even putting in the spaces.